# iOS App Store shows iCloud button instead of Install button

Tags: ios, app-store, icloud

When users who previously had our iOS 6 app installed on their iPhone, go to the App Store to reinstall our app, they see an iCloud button instead of the INSTALL button.

When they push the iCloud button the App Store installs the version of our app they installed in the past, instead of the latest version. Immediately after the installation the iCloud button changes into an UPDATE button offering to update the app to the latest version.

How can we prevent this behaviour, because the user actually downloads our app twice?
Our app is for free, so there is no need to install a "previously purchased" version.

Also if the user presses the UPDATE button fast, things get screwed up. For some reason this leads to our app being unable to save data to the Documents folder.

This is new behaviour. Have never seen this in the past. Anyone got a clue? The name of our app is Rogerthat

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. This may be better suited to Apple's discussion forums.

Comment: I hoped there might be a flag in the iOS app project that controls this behaviour

Comment: No. There is nothing about an iOS app that addresses this behavior.

Comment: File a bug with Apple, this is a problem with the App Store app. And, it's really off topic for this site.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, App Store showing cloud icon instead of Update button when previous version is already installed in iPhone. Did someone find the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue could be caused if the version set in iTunes Connect and the version set in the info.plist don't match up. For example, we've seen this issue when the version in iTunes Connect was set to `1.01` and the version in the info.plist as `1.0.1`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, App Store showing cloud icon instead of Update button when previous version is already installed in iPhone. Did someone find the solution to this issue?